# How to get root directory in yii2

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

**yii2 Question**

My yii2 install in `d:\wamp\www\yii2store`

I want to get above path to save images which will be uploaded by me or users.

I have pass all available arguments in `Yii::getAlias('@webroot')` (below are the lists of argument which I have used).

`@yii` - framework directory.

`@app` - base path of currently running application.

`@runtime` - runtime directory.

`@vendor` - Composer vendor directory.

`@webroot` - web root directory of currently running web application.

`@web` - base URL of currently running web application.

And also once I will get above path to save images then how can I get path something like this `localhost/yiistore2/upload` to be use in img tag src.

One more thing how can I create my own alias with `Yii::setAlias()` and where to create this so that I can load it on every controller.

Comment: Here is a list of the default aliases available in Yii2 : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/

Comment: Already gone through but could not get what I want, so below is the right solution.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Open file
`D:\wamp\www\yiistore2\common\config\params-local.php`

Paste below code before return

```
Yii::setAlias('@anyname', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

After inserting above code in params-local.php file your file should look like this.

```
Yii::setAlias('@anyname', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));

return [
];
```

Now to get path of your root (in my case its `D:\wamp\www\yiistore2`) directory you can use below code in any php file.

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@anyname');
```

Comment: How to get URL of this directory?

Comment: This is the location of root directory. What do you mean by URL of this directory kindly show me some example with regards to this question.

Answer (score 49):

Use "getAlias" in Yii2

```
   \Yii::getAlias('@webroot')
```

Answer (score 29):

Try out this,

My installation is at D:\xampp\htdocs\advanced

`\Yii::$app->basePath` will give like `D:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend`.

`\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl` will give like `localhost\advanced\backend\web\`

You may store the image using `\Yii::$app->basePath` and show it using `\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl`

Answer (score 6):

Supposing you have a writable "uploads" folder in your application:

You can define a param like this:

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/uploads/';
```

Then you can simply use the parameter as:

```
$path1 = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $filename;
```

Just depending on if you are using advanced or simple template the base path will be (following the [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/) provided by phazei):

> Simple @app: Your application root directory
>
> Advanced @app: Your application root directory (either frontend or
>   backend or console depending on where you access it from)

This way the application will be more portable than using `realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the root directory of your yii2 project use, assuming that the name of your project is **project_app** you'll need to use:

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@app');
```

on windows you'd see "C:\dir\to\project_app"

on linux you'll get "/var/www/dir/to/your/project_app"

I was formally using:

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/..';
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

To get the base URL you can use this (would return "http:// localhost/yiistore2/upload")

```
Yii::app()->baseUrl
```

The following Code would return just "localhost/yiistore2/upload" without http[s]://

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)
```

Or you could get the webroot path  (would return "d:\wamp\www\yii2store")

```
Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')
```

Comment: I have already try these methods, they are no longer available in yii2.

Comment: in yii2: `Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBasseUrl()`

Comment: for Yii2 you can get the base path with Yii::$app->basePath

Comment: still does not answer the question how to get the baseUrl like so:

    https://localhost/ 

Yii::$app->basePath will give something like:
/Users/xxx/src/yii2-app

Answer (score 0):

Open below file `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\common\config\params-local.php`

Before your code:

```
<?php

return [


];
```

after your code:

```
<?php
yii::setAlias('@path1', 'localhost/foodbam/backend/web');

return [


];
```