# Yii2 display the base path

Tags: php, yii2

How to get the base path in yii2.

```
<?php echo Yii::app->getBaseUrl() ?>
```

not working

KIndly fix this

Comment: Missing semi colon `;` at end of statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get root directory in yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155428/how-to-get-root-directory-in-yii2)

Comment: @Rikesh,  ; is not required if it's single statement enclosed in php tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the yii 1.0 version syntax .It was not supported in yii 2.0

This will helpfull to you

This is in yii2.0 syntax

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use :

```
<?php echo \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl; ?>
```