# Get Root Directory in yii2 advanced app

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, base-url

I want to get root directory of my project in yii2 advanced app.

My Url is like following

```
http://localhost:83/Working-copy/mySite/backend/web/index.php
```

I have used

```
Yii::setAlias('@anyname', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));

 echo Yii::getAlias('@anyname');
```

but it gives me

```
/var/www/Working-copy/mySite
```

i have used

```
Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl
```

But it also gives

```
/Working-copy/mySite/backend/web
```

i only want

```
/Working-copy/mySite
```

Any Help??

Comment: i have same situation if you have solution for that please help me thanks

Comment: @renishkhunt see my answer. it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

1. Create components into common folder.
2. Add Request.php

   ```
   namespace common\components;


   class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
       public $web;
       public $adminUrl;

       public function getBaseUrl(){
           return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
       }

       public function getActualBaseUrl(){
           return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl());
       }

       public function resolvePathInfo(){
           if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
               return "";
           }else{
               return parent::resolvePathInfo();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use `Yii::$app->request->getActualBaseUrl(). // this gives me /Working-copy/mySite`

Comment: created file Request.php in your specified location now .Getting unknown property: yii\web\Request::getBaseUrl

Answer (score 0):

You have two apps, backend and frontend, and each has a different BaseURL. The path `/Working-copy/mySite` it's not a BaseURL for any app. But you can have this value if you set in params.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set it in params?

Comment: For example, in params-local.php define the following:

`return [
    'path' => '/Working-copy/mySite',
];`

And then, you can use with `Yii::$app->params['path']` globally.

Comment: I will become static. that path is in my local. but on server it will like `mySite `. so that i want only root directory.

Comment: Try aliases `Yii::getAlias('@web')` or define yours. Here's a list of all aliases in Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/. Also, a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155428/how-to-get-root-directory-in-yii2