# yii2-advanced:how can i save image in backend and view that in backend and frontend?

Tags: yii2, frontend, backend, yii2-advanced-app

hi i am save image in frontend and that show in frontend true and i test with many way to view that in backend but don't work.
please help me

my controller in backend

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] =  Yii::getAlias('@frontend')  .'/web/uploads/';
          $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->image_web_filename;
           $image->saveAs($path);
```

url my backend and frontend is seperate

```
 backend:yii.com/:81
 frontend:yii.com
```

i test these soloution but didn't work true:

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155428/how-to-get-root-directory-in-yii2
```

i inset two alias in aliases file in backend\config:

```
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', 'http://frontend.sample.dev');
Yii::setAlias('@backend', 'http://backend.sample.dev');
```

and use that in backend/web/index.php

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php');
```

but i get this error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "site/error".' in 
/var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:532
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(95): 
yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#1 /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): 
yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-
>handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "post/index".' in 
/var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:532
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): 
yii\base\Module->runAction('post/index', Array)
#1 /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): 
yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /var/www/blog/backend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

 Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not 
 found.' in /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:114
 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): 
yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/blog/backend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Comment: what is it the value of `Yii::getAlias('@backend')`

Comment: Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');

Comment: can you give us $path for one of your files and the path you set for your images to show in frontend

Comment: url that my image in frontend have : src="uploads/'.$model->image_web_filename.'"
url that my image have: blog/frontend/web/uploads/'.$model->image_web_filename.'"

Comment: this error is not related to aliases,this tell that yii can't route to  `post/index` do you have PostController.php file and how you call url , like this `index.php?r=post/index`  or `index.php/post/index`

Comment: yes i have because i load this page this url show error. for each page this diffrent and when i use alias shoe this error whith out this work fine.i use index.php/post/index

Comment: can you provide your question with aliases that you have added?

Comment: yes i updated the question

Comment: if you remove two lines in aliases.php you get this error again? and you replaced `http://frontend.sample.dev` with your real front end path?

Comment: when i remove two lines in aliases i did not get error. yes i replaced that with:http://yii.com

Comment: you should not replace with yii.com, you have to replace it with `localhost`  path to your project.for example `http://localhost/frontend/` or path you have

Comment: i decided to save image in frontend and backend together and use them. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty late to the party
but i got a few bones to pick with [this solution provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45130383/374509).. so here it goes:

1. you mention you have different front and back configurations
   so you are serving different folders for `yii.com/:80` and `yii.com/:81` respectively `/frontend/web` and `/backend/web`.
   keeping this in mind,
   **no amount of aliases can make content of one of them available to the other.**
2. the yii-advanced-app has `@frontend` and `@backend` aliases defined in [common/config/bootstrap](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php)

   ```
   Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
   Yii::setAlias('@frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
   Yii::setAlias('@backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
   Yii::setAlias('@console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
   ```

   **DO NOT CHANGE THESE** unless you know very well what you're doing.
   Yii is using these aliases to autoload classes defined under these namespaces common, frontend, backend and console. this exact thing is causing the ridiculous chain of "errors occurring while handling other errors"
   more details on [Yii autloading documentaion](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html)

---

you can simply share content of these folders by creating a symlink from `frontend/web/uploads` to `backend/web/uploads`.

your webserver config (or .htaccess) will require the `+FollowSymLinks` option

Yii can manage this if you add a few lines to the `environments/index.php` file

```
'Development' => [
    // .. other options
    'setWritable'            => [
        // .. leave the default stuff there
        'frontend/web/uploads',
    ],
    'createSymlink'          => [
        // link                =>   real folder
        'backend/web/uploads'  => 'frontend/web/uploads',
    ]
],
'Production'  => [
    // .. 
    'setWritable'            => [
        // .. 
        'frontend/web/uploads',
    ],
    'createSymlink'          => [
        // link                =>   real folder
        'backend/web/uploads'  => 'frontend/web/uploads',
    ]
],
```

and then run the init command again, just like in the installation guide (you do have to option to not overwrite local config files)
if you are running under windows, this  might now ask you for elevated privileges

```
php init
```

or if you chose to make the symlinks manually you can try this [quick guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution :

```
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', 'http://frontend.sample.dev');
Yii::setAlias('@backend', 'http://backend.sample.dev');
```

and if you upload files in backend set the `src` parameter of image to

```
Yii::getAlias('@backend/path/to/your/image/file');
```

and if you save your files in frontend replace `@backend` with `@frontend`

Comment: no i edit my code my file savo to /frontend/web/uploads and i want show that in backend. how can do that?i want show this pic in frontend and backend together.

Comment: its not parameter.you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file to set aliases

Comment: Dear @tara, unfortunately, I can't help you remotely because this post must help others too, so If you can you can give me some more detail of errors you got I can help your more

Answer (score -1):

create this function in components folder

```
   namespace common\components;

use Yii;

class Helper extends \yii\web\Request {

    public static function getFrontendUrl($path) {
        $frontUrl = str_replace('/adminpanel', '', $path);
        return $frontUrl;
    }

}
```

and use in  backend :

$path \common\components\Helper::getFrontendUrl(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl).$img;

> notic: in frontend You do not need

Comment: thank you for your answer but i put this function where?

Comment: you can use create class in components folder.i use in components folder and create helper class .and use  like this: `code`Helper::getFrontendUrl(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl) .$path`code`

Comment: i write that function and use that but not work true and image load from backend.

Comment: please message me . @amirajloo in telegram .